# UINavigationBar - Hide Subview in nested pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have added a message count using the MKNumberBadgeView via the following code in my uiTableView Homepage -

```
-(void)counterBtn{

    _numberBadge = [[MKNumberBadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, -10, 40, 40)];
    _numberBadge.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239.0/255.0 green:117.0/255.0 blue:33/255.0 alpha:0];
    _numberBadge.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239.0/255.0 green:117.0/255.0 blue:33/255.0 alpha:1];
    _numberBadge.shine = NO;
    _numberBadge.hideWhenZero = YES;
    _numberBadge.value = _countBtnNo;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:_numberBadge];

}
```

All works fine - but if I navigate from this view to a subview the counter is still shown over the back button as in screenshot -

[image]

Is it possible to temporarily hide this button - then show it again when I return to the homepage?

I was thinking something along these lines in the subview's viewdidload method? -

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `HomeScreen`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    _numberBadge.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    _numberBadge.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: cheers @Visput - I get the error  - 'use of undeclared identifier_numberBadge' not sure how I would reference get a reference to this subview to hide it?

Comment: @Dancer where did you declare _numberBadge instance variable? I thought that it was in HomeScreen